# (java/math) how to find quotient in mod?

Tags: java, math, cryptography, discrete-mathematics, modulus

This may be a rather simple problem. I'll show an example.

I have *A* and *B* (take it as client and server set-up). *A* does the following 
`(2^10) mod 23 = 12`.

It then sends the value 12 over to *B*

Now, *B* has the equation `12 = (2^x) mod 23`. (It has the modulus and the base value). How would I find the value 10? I tried inverse mod, but that seems to work only for a power of -1. Google doesn't seem to help much either. Just the math help would be great, but if there is a Java function for it, it would be even better.

Comment: Could you please post your code as well as some inputs and outputs so we can better understand where you're struggling/What you are trying to do

Comment: @GBlodgett There is no code involved in my question, although I will need to write the code for it later. From 12 = (2^10) mod 23, I need a way to find the value 10, assuming that it is unknown. That means, I have 12 = (2^r) mod 23, and need to find r.

Comment: Hint: the inverse function for (2^x) is log base 2 (implemented `Math.log(x)/Math.log(2);` in Java)

Comment: So is this more of a maths question than a programming question?

Comment: @khelwood It is a math question, but I need it for programming. That means, if there is a function in a java package which will help me solve this, I need that more than a math solution right now.

Comment: The problem with finding the inverse of the modulus operator is that it is a many-to-one function, so you can't reproduce the values that were originally passed in, unless you know they were in some range, say [0, 23).

Comment: This is called the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), and is a well studied problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sometimes find the solution by trying with the first values and see what happens :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + i +" : " + (int)Math.pow(2, i) % 23);
    }
}
```

Here is the result :

```
0 : 1
1 : 2
2 : 4
3 : 8
4 : 16
5 : 9
6 : 18
7 : 13
8 : 3
9 : 6
10 : 12
11 : 1
12 : 2
13 : 4
14 : 8
15 : 16
16 : 9
17 : 18
18 : 13
19 : 3
20 : 6
21 : 12
22 : 1
23 : 2
24 : 4
25 : 8
26 : 16
27 : 9
28 : 18
29 : 13
30 : 3
31 : 5
32 : 5
33 : 5
```

I cut the output but for each value after 33, the result will be `5`, because of some overflows.

But you can see that there is a loop in the results : `1 2 4 8 16 9 18 13 3 6 12`.

This is explained because of this mathematical relationship :

```
(2^(n+1)) mod 23 = ((2 ^ n) mod 23) * 2 mod 23
```

(in english, multiply the previous result by 2 and apply a mod 23 if necessary)

So

- when `n = 10`, the result is 12
- when `n = 11`, the result is 12 * 2 mod 23 = 24 mod 23 = 1 and there you go for a new cycle 1, 2, 4 etc

Hence the answer is that eihter you find the corresponding value in the first 10 tries or you will never find it.
Trying to find a value of `5` or `7` will end in an infinite loop.

Comment: This is a good method, but what if the numbers are bigger? It may be a bit impractical to try 1000s of numbers...

Comment: @dancerdiver101 I edited the answer. I showed that there is actually a loop (which is mathematically proven) in the results.

Comment: @dancerdiver101 A more general reasoning is that there is a relationship `u(n+1) = f(u(n))` and because of the modulo, `u(n)` has less that `23` distinct values so you are sure to loop at most at the `23th` step. Same reasonning could be applied if you had `1000` instead of `23`, you are sure to loop before the `1000th` step.

Answer (score 1):

The property we can use to solve this is that *A* can only have 23 unique outputs.  Therefore you can precalculate all the values that you might pass into the left hand side of *B*, and record the inputs that get those values, until you get a full list:

```
2^0 % 23 == 1
2^1 % 23 == 2
2^2 % 23 == 4
2^3 % 23 == 8
2^4 % 23 == 16
2^5 % 23 == 9
2^6 % 23 == 18
2^7 % 23 == 13
2^8 % 23 == 3
2^9 % 23 == 6
2^10 % 23 == 12
   .
   .
   .
```

You will find that after the 10th output, there is a repeating sequence of the above values, so those are the only values that *B* should take as input.

Comment: I don't agree. I think that the reasoning does not prove that you won't find the 23th value at the 1 000 000th step. So it does not tell when the program will end or if it will end in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You've given the proof in your answer, it is mathematically proven to repeat, and therefore you will never get a value outside of the ones I listed. I'm not sure what it is that you don't agree with...

Comment: Oh yeah I see what you're saying.  Yeah in the general case (for arbitrary _A_), you can't be sure that you will get all the values for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to add this:

Basically after certain loop due to `2^11 mod 23 = 1` and `(a * b) mod c = (a mod c) * (b mod c) mod c`, which is the [mod multiplication rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416119/rules-for-modulus-and-multiplication).

So we can definitely use the `loop` to get the final result using just a simple list (no matter how big the `i` might be) as:

```
 int getMod(int i) {
     int[] ret = new int {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 9, 18, 13, 3, 6, 12};
     return ret[i % 11];
 }
```

To OP, there is a [tutorial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Modular_arithmetic/Introduction#Multiplication_rule) explaining well about the math solving program problems. Might it be helpful.